# PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf not found in DirectMemory

Tags: java, memory, netty, directmemory

I am using Netty 4.1.17-Final.

I wrote the code to send and receive 100 MB random ASCII. Decoder does not read until ByteBuf becomes 100 MB.

```
@Override
public void decode(ByteBuffer _in, List<Object> _out) {
    if (_in.remaining() == size) {   // size = 100 * 1024 * 1024
        _in.get(new byte[size]);
    }
}
```

Therefore, Netty buffers 100 MB, but it was not found even by monitoring Direct Memory.

```
System.out.println(sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaNioAccess().getDirectBufferPool().getMemoryUsed());
ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBeans(BufferPoolMXBean.class).forEach(buf -> {
    System.out.printf("%s: Used=%d, TotalCap=%d%n", buf.getName(), buf.getMemoryUsed(), buf.getTotalCapacity());
});

// Result
// 10
// direct: Used=9, TotalCap=8
// mapped: Used=0, TotalCap=0
```

Netty used PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf, but where do you buffer the received data? Or is the direct buffer monitoring method incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell Netty to not use `Unsafe` for the direct buffers and so have it show up in JMX again. Unfortunally this also will have some performance impact.

Just use `-Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory=0`.

See: https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/internal/PlatformDependent.java#L153

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
My code now uses DirectBuffer.

I found "io.netty.noUnsafe" and "io.netty.noPreferDirect".
What is the difference between these and "io.netty.maxDirectMemory = 0"?

Comment: `..noUnsafe` disable the usage of `sun.misc.Unsafe` completely (which comes with a performance overhead in general). `...noPreferDirect` will have `allocator.buffer()` return an heap buffer and not a direct buffer. This may result in more memory copies. `...maxDirectMemory=0` will just ensure we use `DirectByteBuffer` under the cover and so JMX will work. So I would advice to use what I suggested if you have no other strong reason for not doing so.

Comment: Thank you politely. I will use `maxDirectMemory = 0` as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Self-answer, In my code Netty had acquired DirectMemory using com.sun.Unsafe. This area can not be captured with BufferPoolMXBean or SharedSecrets.

I tried to get memory with Unsafe, but it was not output to the monitoring result.

```
Field unsafeField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
unsafeField.setAccessible(true);
Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) unsafeField.get(null);
unsafe.allocateMemory(1000);
```

I found the following request.
[extension for tracking off-heap memory use for netty · Issue #475 · Netflix/spectator](https://github.com/Netflix/spectator/issues/475#issuecomment-334165469)

Please tell me if there is a way to get the size obtained by Unsafe.